# GCP Pubsub high latency on low message/sec

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I'm publishing Pubsub messages from AppEngine Flexible environment with the JAVA client library like this:

```
Publisher publisher = Publisher
                .newBuilder(ProjectTopicName.of(Utils.getApplicationId(), "test-topic"))
                .setBatchingSettings(
                        BatchingSettings.newBuilder()
                                .setIsEnabled(false)
                                .build())
                .build();

publisher.publish(PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
                .setData(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message))
                .putAttributes("timestamp", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .build());
```

I'm subscribing to the topic in Dataflow and logging how long it takes for the message to reach Dataflow from AppEngine flexible

```
pipeline
            .apply(PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(Utils.buildPubsubSubscription(Constants.PROJECT_NAME, "test-topic")))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<PubsubMessage, PubsubMessage>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.parseLong(c.element().getAttribute("timestamp"));
                    System.out.println("Time: " + timestamp);
                }
            }));
    pipeline.run();
```

When I'm publishing messages at the rate of a few messages per second then the logs show that the time needed for  the message to reach Dataflow is between 100ms and 1.5 seconds.
But when the rate is about 100 messages per second then the time is constantly between 100ms - 200ms, which seems totally adequate.
Can someone explain this behavior. It seems as turning off the publisher batching does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Pub/Sub is designed for high throughput messages for both Subscription cases.

Pull subscription works best when there's large volume of messages, it's the kind of subscription you would use when throughput of message processing is your priority. Specially note that synchronous pull doesn't handle messages as soon as they are published, and can choose to pull and handle a fixed number of messages (more messages, more pulls). A better option would be to use asynchronous pull, which uses a long running message listener and acknowledges one message at a time [1].

On the other hand, Push subscription uses a slow-start algorithm: The number of messages sent is doubled with each successful delivery until it reaches its constraints (more messages, more -and faster- deliveries).

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull

Comment: As far as I know I can not use Push subscription with dataflow. Neither can I use asynchronous pull. So I should create empty messages when there are not enough "real" messages for my topic, so that they would be delivered faster?